# Docker: How to join containers into host network?

Tags: docker, networking, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-network

I would like to treat a container like a "physical" machine in the network, for example:

Instead of:

- Host 1: (192.168.0.2)

  - Container 1: (172.17.0.2)
  - Container 2: (172.17.0.3)
- Host 2: (192.168.0.3)

  - Container 1: (172.17.0.2)
  - Container 2: (172.17.0.3)

I would like to have something similar to:

- Host 1: (192.168.0.2)

  - Container 1: (192.168.0.4)
  - Container 2: (192.168.0.5)
- Host 2: (192.168.0.3)

  - Container 1: (192.168.0.6)
  - Container 2: (192.168.0.7)

So that if I have another machine (192.168.0.10), I can directly connect 192.168.0.7 (Host 2 Container 2) like normal. Similarly, if I'm in 192.168.0.7, I can connect to the host network devices, such as 192.168.0.10

I have tried both `--network host` and `--network bridge` but both does not work.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: you have to use docker swarm for this use-case.

Comment: Agree with @Munish: Docker swarm or Kubernetes

Comment: How do you do this with other processes that run on your host?  If you start, say, a non-Docker Nginx server, how do you assign it its own IP address?

Comment: @Max thanks for the suggestion about kubernetes, however after reading the network doc for k8s, I can't figure out which network model to use. Would you mind enlighting my monkey brain? Thanks.